# Kendo Template: error in evaluating variable values inside C# code block

Tags: c#, templates, variables, razor, kendo-ui

I have a problem evaluating variable values inside Kendo Template.

In this code, the variable ***controlID*** was evaluated as expected. It returns **"test"**.

```
<script id="treeview-template" type="text/kendo-ui-template">
    # var controlID= "test"; # 
    @Html.CheckBox("#=controlID#")
</script>
```

But when I used it in a C# code block, the variable was evaluated as ***"#=controlID#"*** instead.

```
<script id="treeview-template" type="text/kendo-ui-template">
    # var controlID= "test"; # 
    @{
       Html.CheckBox("#=controlID#");
     }
</script>
```

How can I get the correct value of the variable inside a C# code block in Kendo Template?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

A [Kendo Template](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/framework/templates/overview) is basically translated to JavaScript and is executed on the client-side (in the browser).

Your first configuration works because the following

```
@Html.CheckBox('#=controlID#')
```

Is rendered as

```
<input type="checkbox" name="#= controlID #" id="#= controlID #" />
```

The latter is a valid Kendo Template.

The other code block however won't output anything because you are using `@{ }` instead of `@`. This just denotes a block of executable server-side code (C#) which doesn't output any HTML.

Phil Haack has an excellent blog post explaining the Razor syntax: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx

Comment: Cant find the perfect solution for this so i just did a work around. But it was helpful though.. +1 Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Kendo myself, but I'd *expect* this to work, based on the syntax you've shown:

```
<script id="treeview-template" type="text/kendo-ui-template">
    # var controlID= "test"; # 
    @{
       Html.CheckBox(controlID);
     }
</script>
```

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't work. In Kendo Templates, in order to evaluate the variable inside an HtmlHelper, you must enclose the variable with this :"#=#". That's why the solution you gave returns a compilation error that says "controlID does not exist". Thanks anyway! :)